# replace a foreach loop with a functional programming approach

Tags: php, functional-programming

Below is an example of a function that adds a constant number to the keys of an array -

```
function addConstantToArrayKeys($seed_array, $constant)
{
    foreach($seed_array as $key => $value){
        $a[$key + $constant] = $value;
    }
    return $a;
}

$basearray = [1 => 17, 2 => 24, 3 => 12];
$test = addConstantToArrayKeys($basearray, 19);
```

The result of this example is:

```
Array
(
    [1] => 17
    [2] => 24
    [3] => 12
)

Array
(
    [20] => 17
    [21] => 24
    [22] => 12
)
```

It works as desired but can this method be rewritten somehow using a functional programming approach that can achieve the same result?

I have tried this:

```
function addConstantToArrayKeys($seed_array, $constant)
{
    return array_map(function($key, $element) use($constant)
         {return $a[$key + $constant] = $element;},
          array_keys($seed_array), array_values($seed_array));
}
```

But it does not handle the keys as desired.  Here is the output -

```
Array
(
    [1] => 17
    [2] => 24
    [3] => 12
)

Array
(
    [0] => 17
    [1] => 24
    [2] => 12
)
```

**Edit -**
Thanks to Progrock's answer, this worked -

```
function addConstantToArrayKeys($seed_array, $constant)
{
    return array_combine(array_map(
        function($key) use($constant) {
            return $key + $constant;
        }, array_keys($seed_array)), $seed_array);
}
```

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of replacing the foreach loop with array_map or array_walk or something that can handle changing the array's keys.

Comment: You can't mutate keys with `array_walk`.

Comment: So why it's my `array_map` attempt working?

Comment: `array_map` does not provide access to the keys.

Comment: Is there a built-in array function that does provide access to the keys?  If so, what is it's name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something unreadable like this.  It does not mutate existing array keys.

```
<?php
$nums = [
    1 => 17,
    2 => 24,
    3 => 12
];

$out = array_combine(array_map(
    function($int) {
        return $int + 10;
}, array_keys($nums)), $nums);

var_export($out);
```

Output:

```
array (
    11 => 17,
    12 => 24,
    13 => 12,
  )
```

Your first example is perfectly functional and readable, but for the naming.

```
<?php

$nums = [
    1 => 17,
    2 => 24,
    3 => 12
];

$add_num_to_keys = function (array $in, $num) {
    $out = [];
    foreach($in as $k => $v)
        $out[$k + $num] = $v;

    return $out;
};


$out = $add_num_to_keys($nums, 10);
var_export($out);
```

Output:

```
array (
    11 => 17,
    12 => 24,
    13 => 12,
  )
```

You can't do:

```
foreach($in as &$k => $v)
    $k += 10;
```

As the key element can't be a reference.

Answer (score 2):

May be its too late but this should work for you as you wanted the **functional** approach.

```
function addConstantToArrayKeys($basearray, $constant){

  $arrayReindexed = [];
  array_walk($basearray,function($v,$k) use (&$arrayReindexed, $constant) {
      $key = $k;
      $k = $key + $constant;
      $arrayReindexed[$k] = $v;
  });

   return $arrayReindexed;
}

$basearray = [1 => 17, 2 => 24, 3 => 12];
$test = addConstantToArrayKeys($basearray, 19);
print '<pre>';
print_r($test);
print '</pre>';
```

**Output:**

```
Array (
     [20] => 17
     [21] => 24
     [22] => 12
 )
```